# Rstudio: shared libraries not easily searched

Tags: emacs, rstudio

I have a 'workflow' type of question about the RStudio gui.  I have multiple projects active, each accessing a number of libraries.  To edit or search the source code for a library function definition and calls,  I need the libraries open because being shared libraries, they are not in the project directory so 'goto file/function' does not apply, nor does the 'function menu'.  This means multiple files open in the code pane, but there is only room for a modest number of tabs along the top - they do not wrap.  I can pull down a menu of them, but they are not alphabetical and cannot be resequenced without close/reopen.  I find this a significant productivity drag.  So: do power users use an external editor for all this functionality, and take advantage of Rstudio's dynamic update of externally edited and saved code?  Which editor?  Does anyone still use WinEdt and RWinEdt?  Is EMACS still living or effectively extinct?  I realise this question may get zapped for being too vague but it is important to me.

Answer (score 1):

emacs is very much alive, and so are the packages that support using it for R development, specifically:

- [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org)
- [polymode](https://github.com/vitoshka/polymode)

Answer (score 0):

To jump to function definition in a library, `ctrl+click` would do. There is an option in `View->Switch to Tab` that you can use to search tabs, which you might need. Reordering tabs is on their todo list https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200661306-Rearrange-Tabs